# Lafalink LF-D10 WLAN Driver Install

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, server

I am new to Ubuntu Server and have installed it on a Proliant G4. This is the new version, 14.04.

I have my system installed and it seems to be doing fine but it has not installed the driver for my wireless USB adapter. I am using the Lafalink LF-D10. The chipset shows up as being RT3070.

I have the driver on an install cd. The driver is 2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.

It does show wlan0 during setup but when I try to let it automatically configure itself it gives an error and the correct device does not show up in the list anyway. It shows 2 wire something or other.

My question is how do I get this on the server and set it up? I do not have internet access to my server and I also do not have a wired network set up. I can use either a cd or usb port but I do not know how to do this. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I have seen many other people making wireless lan's using this same chip setup but they were all hooked up to the internet with their servers and did not have to do this my way.

How can I manually get this to work? I have been waiting for months for this new Ubuntu release but it does not work either.

I would appreciate any help that I can get to get my server set up for wireless use.

Comment: The necessary driver rt2800usb is included by default. Is it loaded? lsmod  Isn't it working as expected?

Comment: How do I find out if it is loaded? Like I said I am really new to this.

Comment: I have used sudo lsusb to find the device and it does show up.

Comment: Please share with us the results from lsusb. Find out if the module (driver) is loaded with lsmod. Look for rt2800usb. Is it there? Was a wireless interface created, ideally wlan0? iwconfig

Comment: lsusb says ralink Technology Corp Rt2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter

Comment: lsusb says ralink Technology Corp Rt2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter

Comment: lsusb says ralink Technology Corp Rt2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter

Comment: I think it says more than that, we need the usb.id as well; something like 9876:3070 or some such.

Comment: lsmod shows rt2800lib as being loaded along with rt2x00usb. It also shows rt2x00usb and rt2x00lib. There also is crc_ccitt being called by rt2800lib. It takes me a while to do this because I have to look up how to use all of the commands as I go.

Comment: You are doing well so far. Is there a wlan0 listed when you issue the command: iwconfig?

Comment: I have eth0 and lo.

Comment: I still need the result of lsusb including the eight digit usb.id.

Comment: OK. Sorry, I thought I had already listed that. The device number is 148f:3070 .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the usual error in dmesg when you insert the device:

```
“Invalid RF chipset 0×3070 detected”
```

If so, your device is not correctly driven in rt2800usb until the changes made in the 3.12 kernel. Please see this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192790&highlight=lafalink where the poster said it was solved by installing the latest kernel. I suggest you do so following post #7 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185682

Upgrade the kernel on a command-line only system as follows. Insert the USB key containing the .debs in the USB slot. Run the command

```
dmesg
```

You will see that the system recognized the USB device as a drive, often enumerated as *sdb*. Yours may differ, but make note of the name. The first partition is where files are usually located, so we will refer to /dev/sdb1.

Now we mount the device. First, we need a place on the system to mount it; in newer Ubuntu systems, we generally use /media.

```
sudo mkdir /media/kernel
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/kernel
```

Now we install the .debs:

```
cd /media/kernel
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and confirm you are now running 3.12:

```
uname -r

3.12.0-031200-generic
```

If you are using a CD, find out its file type with:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sr0
```

You may find that the type is iso9660. In that case, I'd try:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media/kernel
```

Then proceed as above.

In a message from the user on ubuntuforums with the same device, he reported that kernel version 3.12.**4** solved the problem. I suggest you download and install from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.4-trusty/ Be sure to get 32- or 64-bit as appropriate.

Comment: As I said before my server is not able to connect to the internet so how is this going to help me? Also, I am using 13.1 so what does 12.04 have to do with me? Are you saying 13.1 does not have the newest kernal?

Comment: Correct. Ubuntu 13.10 has the latest stable kernel as of the feature freeze I suspect in August, 2013 or so. Please check: uname -r. My 13.10 machine has 3.11.0-xx. The latest stable kernel as of 12-12-13 is 3.12.5. You can certainly download the deb files for the 3.12 kernel to a USB drive, transfer and install them, can't you? You want 3.12-saucy. I know of no way to install a driver for your device without downloading something.

Comment: OK. I see what you mean. I still do not know how to move the files by usb drive or cd though. I can download the files when I go to town to my laptop.

Comment: Does your server have a desktop or is it simply a command prompt?

Comment: I am using the command prompt right now. I would like to move to a gui.

Comment: I went and go the downloads yesterday and am ready to update when I learn how to do it.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I have tried using sudo mount -t vfat /dev/cdrom /media/kernel bu tI get an error saying wrong file structure and /dev/sr0 is write protected. I am wanting to do this with cdrom if I can. I cannot find my flash drive.

Comment: I have tried updating the kernel twice and both times it has effected my video driver and now I cannot see anything.

Comment: I think video is another new question. I assume that the video can't start and it boots to a command prompt. You might look for clues: cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE

Comment: I do not have a command prompt. All I have is a black screen.

Comment: OK. I was able to use the grub boot from recovery and now my video is back and I have the command prompt. A small victory for me.

Comment: I am sowing that the kernel is updated. Now, how do I get my wlan to work? I have checked using my windows laptop and the wlan is not showing up yet so how do I use it?

Comment: I have tried removing and re-inserting the usb wifi lan and it still shows the same error even with the kernel upgrade. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: OK. I am now trying to use 14.04 LTS and it still does not pick up the correct device. It does show wlan0 during setup but when I try to let it automatically configure itself it gives an error and the correct device does not show up in the list anyway. It shows 2 wire something or other.

How can I manually get this to work? I have been waiting for months for this new Ubuntu release and now it does not work either.

I would appreciate any help that I can get to get my server set up for wireless use.

Comment: Is Network Manager running here? Is that the list you see? '2wire-something' sounds like a nearby wireless access point.

Comment: As far as I know there is no network manager working. Where I saw it at was when I was installing 14.04. It gave me a choice between wireless devices and I think the 'two wire' was the only choice. I do have a wireless router set up but it is not connected to the server.

Comment: I just checked my wireless connections and it is picking up the wireless router in my room so I guess that means that the wireless from the server is working. My next question is how do I connect my wireless laptops to the server? They both use windows.

Comment: Hooking laptops to the server is a whole different subject for a whole new question. Do you need any further help getting the server connected to the internet?

Comment: I am not wanting to hook it up to the internet. I am wanting to use it as a wireless home server. That was what this question was about.

Comment: OK; I suggest you start a new question; something like "How to make my server accessible to other computers in the network."